# Vertically align different img sizes in different div sizes where the img is larger than the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align images inside divs vertically... not a problem.

My problem arises with these conditions.

1. The images will be undetermined & different sizes.
2. The images are larger than the divs and need to be masked by the divs.
3. The site that uses this is built on the 320 & up template, calling media queries to render the
   page for different screen sizes & therefor the containing divs differ depending on screen size.
4. When viewed on smart phone/tablet devices the containing div will change size when the device is turned (no page refresh) – the image needs to remain centered.

I can't use `display:table-cell` because the images are larger than the div so with this option the hieght of the divs and `overflow:hidden` don't work.

I tried jQuery vAlign which works great.. if you're not changing the screen size (such as turning a device). As it's is called on `(document).ready` the page needs refreshing to update the alignment of the images.

Is there a way to trigger vAlign via media query?
If not is there a hack/fix to the table-cell method which will allow the smaller `div` to mask the larger `img` with `overfolw:hidden` ?

UPDATE:
Been playing around with pure CSS ([working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/jwoodcreative/TvH3t/)) but still can't get it to work :(

Comment: SURELY THERE IS A WAY OVER MASKING/CROPPING AN OVERSIZED IMAGE INSIDE AN ELEMENT AND CENTRING IT VERTICALLY!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you meant, but if I understood correctly, using the following structure

```
<div class="vertical">
    <div class="wrapper"><img src="image.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS

```
div.vertical { display:table-cell } 
div.wrapper { display:block;position:relative;overflow:hidden; }
div.wrapper img { position:absolute; }
```

You should be able to mask (as in crop?) the picture and be able to align them vertically. Note that the `div.vertical` class is just a dummy div to show which of the divs would be the on to align vertically at the moment and you should replace only the contents of that div in your application.

Comment: It's a god point about adding the extra div, but still couldn't get this to work. I'm looking into something like this now which is starting to work better but still has bugs  `$(window).resize(function() { 
  $(".img-wrapper").vAlign();
 });`

Comment: You definitely don't need javascript to fix your layout. Try setting the div.wrapper display attribute to inline, inline-block etc.

Comment: I don't think this method is going to work... http://jsfiddle.net/jwoodcreative/TvH3t/

Comment: Perhaps the http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp will help you? This should clip of the excess